# How to set gmail (browser) as default mail app in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, gmail

When I click on email links, I want my browser to open up with gmail instead of opening up a mail client.  I don't use mail clients, I prefer to do everything in the browser (Using Firefox).  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: [How to Set Gmail as Your Browser's Default Email Client for Mailto Links](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the Windows 10 default mailto handler to a program not listed](https://superuser.com/questions/972464/set-the-windows-10-default-mailto-handler-to-a-program-not-listed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I set Gmail in Firefox as the default mail app?

> 1. Click the Firefox menu button, click "Options", then click "Options" again.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Click the "Applications" tab.
> 3. Enter "mailto" in the search bar.
> 4. Click the drop-down arrow next to the "Action" column.
> 5. Select "Use Gmail".
> 6. Click "OK".
>
>    [image]

Source [Firefox: How to Set Gmail as Your Default Email Client](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht)

Note:

- The above link shows how to do this for Safari, Chrome and IE, as well as Firefox.

Comment: Note, the link shows how to do this for the big 4 browsers, (Safari, Chrome, IE, and FF)

Comment: @GiH Good point. Added note to answer.